# If you go, bring/take your lunch

Tags: word-choice, verbs

1. > If you go, bring your lunch.
2. > If you go, take your lunch.

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: If you go there, take your lunch. If you come here, bring your lunch.

Comment: Related: [I'll take you home / I'll bring you home](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64016/70061)

Answer (score 8):

Both are understandable, but there is a difference in meaning based on the speaker's *frame of reference*.

If **the speaker is not going with you**, then "If you go, take your lunch" is most natural.

If **the speaker is at the destination** already, then they sound most natural saying "If you *come*, bring your lunch"

"If you go, bring your lunch" is an interesting case.

This has both the person moving *away* from the speaker, and the lunch coming *towards* the speaker. This seems like a contradiction, but has a few uses!

If the speaker:

- **will be at the destination**
- **will not be travelling with you**
- AND **is not already there**

Then they might say "if you go, bring your lunch".

For example, you and your friends are all meeting at a park and your friend calls you on the phone before leaving.

Another case for this usage is if **the speaker is empathizing strongly with you**, like perhaps a parent to their child - especially if there is a sense of teaching or admonishing.

Comment: +1, looks good. Just wanted to add the definitions from wiktionary. *[Take, 9.1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take)*: (transitive) To carry with one, especially to another place. *[Bring, 1:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring)* (transitive) To transport toward somebody/somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. They each imply the same thing: If you go, have your lunch with you.

Comment: this answer doesn't help to clarify the differences.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest that it depends on knowledge about the person and if they have a lunch already.

If the speaker knows they have a lunch:

- If you go, bring your lunch.

If the speaker doesn't know if they have a lunch or not:

- If you go, take **a** lunch.

Comment: What about "If you go, bring **a** lunch."? That's also perfectly idiomatic.